# How do I apply a texture to only 1 face?

Tags: texturing

Since Blender 2.8 I cannot seem to texture only 1 face. I have done this before in Blender 2.79, but now it seems to have changed completely. Is this still possible in Blender 2.8, or do I have to switch to Texture Painting?

Comment: Were you using Blender Internal in 2.79?

Comment: @lemon Yes, I was.

Comment: OK, so the problem should be Blender Internal is no more. Have you ever used Cycles in 2.79? If yes, this is the same material nodes approach.

Comment: I know that Blender Render is gone now, but I haven't used Cycles. I'll look it up how to do it with Cycles

Comment: If you don't want to use (or see) nodes, magic buttons are the little circles on right of the material parameters. If have a principled bdsf for instance (should be the default), just click on this circle corresponding to base color and you'll find what you want.

Comment: @lemon Thank you for your help! I've got it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to put a texture on one face of a model you have to

1. select that face and unwrap it or alternatively scale the existing uv map so that that specific face matches the image
2. add a material
3. add the image as a texture to the material
4. either change the image from repeating to clipping and overlay it ontop of the existing node tree using a mix shader or mixrgb node **or** create a new material and a new material slot, add the image to the material and apply it to the single face in  edit mode.

(Without any specific information it is hard to give a more convenient set of steps for doing it.)

Comment: Needed a bit of extra help (probably because I'm a bit of an idiot), but worked in the end. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it worked in Blender 2.79. But if you want to add texture to a single face you have to go to Edit-Mode and then mark your face. Create a new material and klick on assign. (The Materials Pannel in 2.8 is on the right side of your Viewport.)

Now you should only have the marked face painted, you are able to add textures by pressing: Use Nodes (also in the Material Panel).

I hope my description works for you, if not let me know.

Greetings Sebbe

Comment: That's how it worked in Blender 2.79, but I can no longer seem to add a texture to the material. In 2.79, it was as easy as going to the texture panel but now, the texture panel isn't even there in edit mode, and in object mode it doesn't seem to apply the texture to the material. What you said about pressing "Use Nodes" doesn't help me with it being either on or off.

Answer (score 1):

In the image I have a pink material (no texture) on the cube. In edit mode I select a single face and create a new material and choose assign to place it onto the selected single face. Under Base Color you can click the small circle and add an image texture.

[image]